# Why does this simple script never end?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have a simple JavaScript function, that looks like this:

```js
countDown();

function countDown() {

  var count = 10;

  document.write(count);

  if (count > 0) {
    count = count-1;;
    setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
  }

}
```

Why does the variable `count` never change?  This function never ends . . .

Comment: Every time you call `countDown` you're reseting the value of count.  Try putting the `var count` outside the function so it's globally scoped.

Comment: count will be reset to 10 every recursion.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Specially after the document has finished loading. See the warning in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29).

Comment: you shouldnt set `var count` inside the function. You reinitialize the variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the countDown() function sets the variable count to ten every time it is called.  A slight scoping change will make the function behave as you might have intended.

```
var count = 10;

countDown();

function countDown() {

  document.write(count);

  if (count > 0) {
    count = count-1;;
    setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
  }

}
```